# Dynamic expressions implementation

Tags: java, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have one source table as : 
`S1       S2       S3       S4
 Hi      There    SSN1     SSN2`

where S1, S2, S3 and S4 are column names.
There is a target table likewise which has three fields: 
`T1       T2       T3`

I have another table which is as follows: 
`Function            Target_Column
 concat(S1,S2)          T1
 substr(S3,1,3)         T2
 substr(S3,3,1)         T3`

I want to have such a mapping in which it can fetch the function name and map according to the function present in the table to the target column specified. My target table now after running the mapping will be: 
`T1         T2       T3
 HiThere   SSN       1`

How can I achieve this?
I have tried using a lookup on FUNCTION column which will have 1 column in output containing the concatenated string of all the functions and target table name. So my output of the lookup would look like this:
 `concat(S1,S2),T1::substr(S3,1,3),T2::substr(S3,3,1),T3`

I then passed this along with the source ports S1 S2 S3 S4 to a java transformation to process. Don't know how to proceed now.
I tried using invokeJExpression.
 I splitted my string with :: as delimiter and stored it in an array arr1.
 So I had 
`arr1[0]=concat(S1,S2),T1
arr1[1]=substr(S3,1,3),T2
arr1[2]=substr(S3,3,1),T3`
 Now I ran this trhough loop and again split this using , as my delimiter and stored into arr2.
 So my arr2 for arr1[0] was like this:
`arr2[0]=concat(S1,S2)
arr2[1]=T1`

Now if I use InvokeJExpression, to what I shall assign its result to?
 I want my expression concat(S1,S2) to be processed and mapped to T1 which is in arr2[1] now. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: Assuming the connections to your tables are achieved with no problem, you should do some string manipulation on the Function column. Are the function names and parameters known? If so a lookup table could be the solution. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think you also can get rid of the lookup table... Just need to correctly arrange your data and manipulate a bit the function string to get the function and the parameters.

Comment: Clarification requested: are the tables in a database?

Comment: Yes. I am using Oracle 11g Database.

Comment: I have tried using a lookup on `FUNCTION` column which will have 1 column in output containing the concatenated string of all the functions and target table name. So my output of the lookup would look like this:
`concat(S1,S2),T1::substr(S3,1,3),T2::concat(S3,3,1),T3`
I then passed this along with the source ports `S1 S2 S3 S4` to a java transformation to process. Don't know how to proceed now.

Comment: What conditions are you using in the lookup? The function table rows do not seem to have a direct link with source table rows.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use the Java API function invokeJExpression() inside Java transformation to derive the target columns.

```
(datatype)invokeJExpression(
                  String expression, 
                  Object[] paramMetadataArray);
```

I guess the hard part would be to parse the concatenated string from your lookup to get the two parameters `expression` and `paramMeradataArray`

expression and paramMeradataArray should be something like below:

```
"concat(X1,X2)", [S1, S2]
"substr(X1,X2,X3)", [S1, 1, 3]
```

Note that you must start the parameters with X and number them consecutively.

**Update:**

Assuming from lookup you are getting the port `lkp='concat(S1,S2)~T1::substr(S3,1,3)~T2::substr(S3,3,1)~T3'`, you can try the following code in Java transformation. However, this code might not work for all functions. For example, passing decimal values will not work.

**Import Packages:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

**On Input Row:**

```
String[] arr1 = lkp.split("::");

for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    String[] arr2 = arr1[i].split("~");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(arr2[0]);
    String params = "";
    if (matcher.find()) {
        params = matcher.group(1);
    }
    String[] param = params.split(",");
    Object[] args1 = new Object[param.length];
    String params1 = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < param.length; j++) {
        int index = j + 1;
        Object arg = new Object();
        params1 = params1 + (!params1.equals("") ? "," : "") + "X"
                + index;
        if (param[j].equals("S1"))
            arg = S1;
        else if (param[j].equals("S2"))
            arg = S2;
        else if (param[j].equals("S3"))
            arg = S3;
        else if (param[j].equals("S4"))
            arg = S4;
        else if (!param[j].startsWith("\'"))
            arg = Integer.parseInt(param[j]);
        else
            arg = param[j];
        args1[j] = arg;
    }

    String exp = matcher.replaceAll("(" + params1 + ")");
    if (arr2[1].equals("T1"))
        T1 = (String) invokeJExpression(exp, args1);
    else if (arr2[1].equals("T2"))
        T2 = (String) invokeJExpression(exp, args1);
    else if (arr2[1].equals("T3"))
        T3 = (String) invokeJExpression(exp, args1);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Samik. I tried using invokeJExpression. 
I splitted my string with :: as delimiter and stored it in an array arr1.
So I had 
`arr1[0]=concat(S1,S2),T1
arr1[1]=substr(S3,1,3),T2
arr1[2]=substr(S3,3,1),T3`
Now I ran this trhough loop and again split this using , as my delimiter and stored into arr2.
So my arr2 for arr1[0] was like this:
`arr2[0]=concat(S1,S2)
arr2[1]=T1`

Now if I use InvokeJExpression, to what I shall assign the result to?
I want my expression concat(S1,S2) to be processed and mapped to T1 which is in arr2[1] now. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: If you split using comma, it will not work, because the parameters are also separated by comma. I have updated the answer with a sample code. Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood the question properly. However if your source and target columns are going to remain same however you expression may change for every run then you can try using parameters with 'Is Expression' checked. Parameter value would be your actual function which will be evaluated in expression transformation wherever you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the simplest way below and let me know if you have further questions,

```
1.Create 3 mapping parameters as $$Map1 , $$Map2 & $$Map3 with any default value.

2.Better to create a Job_Parameter table to store parameter and its corresponding value like :

Workflow Name | Parameter Name | Parameter value
wf_abc | $$Map1 | default
wf_abc | $$Map2 | default
wf_abc | $$Map3 | default

3. Create a mapping / unix script / SQL procedure to read your functions and keep those in to this Job_Parameter table, your table should look like this.
(Job_Parameter is always truncate and load).

Workflow Name | Parameter Name | Parameter value
wf_abc | $$Map1 | concat(S1,S2) 
wf_abc | $$Map1 | substr(S3,1,3)
wf_abc | $$Map1 | substr(S3,3,1)

4. Create a parameter file using this Job_Parameter table and it should look like this:

[Global]
wf_abc
 $$Map1=concat(S1,S2) 
 $$Map1=substr(S3,1,3)
 $$Map1=substr(S3,3,1)

4. Go to you Actual mapping and read the source with 4 columns, 
 create 3 variable ports next to SQ 
V1= $$Map1
V2= $$Map2
V3= $$Map3 ..Create 3 output ports and assign these variable ports accordingly.
Source-SQualifier-Expression-Target
```

Link output ports to Target.

I hope all the filed name which you receive in functions source and NAMED in Informatica are on and the same, if not make changes accordingly.